# Excel macro to delete all rows on all worksheets if the value in column AA = 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook containing 197 sheets.  I need to delete all rows in each sheet if the value in column AA is zero.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to delete each row if and only if *that row's* column AA is zero, then the below should work for you.

```
Sub delete0rows()
    Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each Worksheet In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lastRow = Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        i = 1
        Do While i <= lastRow
            If Worksheet.Range("AA" & i).Value = 0 Then
                Worksheet.Rows(i).Delete
                i = i - 1
                lastRow = lastRow - 1
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```

Note this will only delete the row if the cell value in AA is 0. There are several subtleties here... Excel will show a 0 even if the cell value is '0 or =0 among other things, and those rows will not be deleted with the above code.