# How to delete rows in Excel based on certain values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 10 sheets. Each sheet has about 30,000 rows with URL. I have a hand full of URLs (about 10 different URLs) that I need to keep the data. Is there a way to delete all the rows from all the worksheet if the first column (Column A - URL) does not contain one of the URL.

for example, I would like to keep we.abc.us, ss.boli.us and 3m.mark.us and delete rest of the rows from all the worksheet in the workbook.

```
Sub delete0rows()

Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

For Each Worksheet In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
lastRow = Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

i = 1

    Do While i <= lastRow

        If Worksheet.Range("A" & i).Value = 0 Then
        Worksheet.Rows(i).Delete i = i - 1
        lastRow = lastRow - 1
        End
    i = i + 1
    Loop
Next Worksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you'll just want to look up how to loop through a range. Loop through each range in each worksheet, and if the cell doesn't have your URL, delete the entire row.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try searching SO for `excel-vba delete rows based` - there are numerous examples of how to delete rows based on certain criteria.

Comment: I should have flagged this as a duplicate of [Excel macro to delete all rows on all worksheets if the value in column AA = 0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24274045/6535336)  (I picked a different one, then realised that this question was asking for multiple worksheets, so retracted that close vote, now I can't close it with the better duplicate :( )

Comment: Sub delete0rows()
    Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each Worksheet In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lastRow = Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        i = 1
        Do While i <= lastRow
            If Worksheet.Range("A" & i).Value = 0 Then
                Worksheet.Rows(i).Delete
                i = i - 1
                lastRow = lastRow - 1
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Next
End Sub

The .value = 0 needs to be dynamic so i can evaluate an array of urls to keep

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you introduce **reverse For loop** using Step -1:

```
Sub delete0rows()

Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

    For Each Worksheet In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    lastRow = Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
            If Worksheet.Range("A" & i).Value = 0 Then
            Worksheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    Next Worksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to tick the answer box, if you liked my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this sub a while back. I cannot remember who the original author was or I would credit them. I did tweak it slightly to pass variables into it

The nice thing about this is you can pass multiple deletion criteria by passing a space separated string

Essentially you can give it a row to start at (in case you have headers) tell it the column to look in, the sheet that column is on and your criteria/criterion. So for example if I want it to start at row 5 checking each row below that on a sheet named 'cleanup' checking column 'D' for the words 'cat' 'dog' and 'fish' I would write

Call DelRow(5,"D","cleanup","cat dog fish")

```
Public Sub DelRow(DataStartRow As Long, SearchColumn As String, SheetName As String, myTextString As String)
' This macro will delete an entire row based on the presence of a predefined word or set of words.
'If that word or set of words is 'found in a cell, in a specified column, the entire row will be 'deleted
'Note the seperator is a space. To change this modify the split parameter
'EXAMPLE CALL: Call DelRow(1, "AH", "Cut Data", "DEL")

Dim X As Long
Dim Z As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FoundRowToDelete As Boolean
Dim OriginalCalculationMode As Integer
Dim RowsToDelete As Range
Dim SearchItems() As String

SearchItems = Split(myTextString)

On Error GoTo ResetCalcs
OriginalCalculationMode = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With Worksheets(SheetName)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, SearchColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.StatusBar = "**** Working on the '" & SheetName & "' Sheet: Number of Rows to be scanned(" & LastRow & "). Deletion keyword " & myTextString & " ***" 'Extra line added

    For X = LastRow To DataStartRow Step -1

        FoundRowToDelete = False

        For Z = 0 To UBound(SearchItems)
            If InStr(.Cells(X, SearchColumn).Value, SearchItems(Z)) Then
                FoundRowToDelete = True
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

        If FoundRowToDelete Then
            If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set RowsToDelete = .Cells(X, SearchColumn)
            Else
                Set RowsToDelete = Union(RowsToDelete, .Cells(X, SearchColumn))
            End If

            If RowsToDelete.Areas.Count > 100 Then
                RowsToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
                Set RowsToDelete = Nothing
            End If
        End If

    Next

End With

If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
    RowsToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
End If

ResetCalcs:
Application.Calculation = OriginalCalculationMode

End Sub
```